# Can i shut down sharepoint services and still open a visual studio project?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

I am looking at the possibility of installing SharePoint Foundation 2010 on my laptop so I don't have the overhead of a VM just to open a Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint project.

The only way I would do this is if I can shut down the App Pool and services. Can I have SharePoint Foundation 2010 installed but nothing running and still develop against the object model (or at least just open a freaking project)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. But you may just run a single web application and test against it while stopping all the others. I don't think it'll cause any performance issues as long as you have a decent rig.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. But remember the [requirements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288751.aspx) to install Sharepoint Foundation 2010.

I think, if you have a machine where you can install it, so you don't need to care about overhead.